# How to download the tar file in node-red.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node-red

I am trying to download the tar file in node-red.

Following is my JavaScript code to download the file.

```
downloadTar(sendObj).then(res => {
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(byte); // pass your byte response to this constructor
        var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "application/tar"});
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var fileName = 'genome.tar';
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
});


function downloadTar(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: nodeRedDownloadTar,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Following is my Node-Red flow, I am reading the file in `a single Buffer Object` and sending it to the http response

[image]

Then following is the response I am getting it from the backend.
[image]

The problem is the tar file is not getting downloaded. I am not sure where I am making the problem.

Comment: This isn't about downloading files with Node-RED, its from Node-RED and it should be no different to any other server. You have checked that you can download the file with curl/wget first?

Comment: Also are you setting a suitable content-type in the http-response node?

Comment: Yes. I tried setting `msg.headers.content-type` value to `application-tar` using `change` node.

Comment: it needs to be `application/tar` not `application-tar`

Comment: You also haven't answered the question about testing with curl/wget

Comment: I used application/tar only. I tried with curl/wget I am getting the chunk as the response but not getting downloaded.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64280090/edit) the question to show how you tested with curl and the full output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following flow is working properly, I'm using the headers option in the http-response node to set the content-type to `appplication/x-tar`

```
[
    {
        "id": "6e993a09.f44244",
        "type": "file in",
        "z": "1c834717.22be01",
        "name": "",
        "filename": "/home/pi/test.tar",
        "format": "",
        "chunk": false,
        "sendError": false,
        "encoding": "none",
        "x": 600,
        "y": 580,
        "wires": [
            [
                "6e7d5f6f.c9477"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "df49df3b.d325b",
        "type": "http in",
        "z": "1c834717.22be01",
        "name": "",
        "url": "/tar",
        "method": "post",
        "upload": false,
        "swaggerDoc": "",
        "x": 380,
        "y": 580,
        "wires": [
            [
                "6e993a09.f44244"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "6e7d5f6f.c9477",
        "type": "http response",
        "z": "1c834717.22be01",
        "name": "",
        "statusCode": "",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/x-tar"
        },
        "x": 800,
        "y": 580,
        "wires": []
    }
]
```